# Is it possible to create a dataframe column with json data which doesn't have a fixed schema?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to create a dataframe column with `JSON` data which does not have a fixed schema. I am trying to write it in its original form as map/object but getting various errors.

I don't want to convert it to a string as I need to write this data in it's original form to the file.

Later this file is used for `json` processing, original structure should not be compromised.

Currently when I try writing data to a file it contain all the escape characters and is considered entire json as a string instead of complex type. Eg

```
    {"field1":"d1","field2":"app","value":"{\"data\":\"{\\\"app\\\":\\\"am\\\"}\"}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make up a schema for the `json` file.

I don't know what output you expect.

As a clue I give you an example and two interesting links:

[spark-read-json-with-schema](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-json-with-schema/)

[spark-schema-explained-with-examples](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-schema-explained-with-examples/)

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructType}

object RareJson {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("RareJson")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","4") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.app.id","RareJson") // To silence Metrics warning
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

  val input = "/home/cloudera/files/tests/rare.json"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    try {
      val structureSchema = new StructType()
        .add("field1",StringType)
        .add("field2",StringType)
        .add("value",StringType,true)

      val rareJson = sqlContext
        .read
        .option("allowBackslashEscapingAnyCharacter", true)
        .option("allowUnquotedFieldNames", true)
        .option("multiLine", true)
        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
        .schema(structureSchema)
        .json(input)

      rareJson.show(truncate = false)

      // To have the opportunity to view the web console of Spark: http://localhost:4041/
      println("Type whatever to the console to exit......")
      scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
      println("SparkContext stopped")
      spark.stop()
      println("SparkSession stopped")
    }
  }
}
```

output

```
+------+------+---------------------------+
|field1|field2|value                      |
+------+------+---------------------------+
|d1    |app   |{"data":"{\"app\":\"am\"}"}|
+------+------+---------------------------+
```

You can try to parse the value column too if it maintain the same format along the all rows.